# DUnit: 'Global' SetUp and TearDown

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, dunit

In DUnit, `SetUp` and `TearDown` are called before (and after, respectively) **each test** method is executed.
In `SetUp`, I create an object that loads data from a file. This is slow, especially if I have many tests.
Is there any way to call `SetUp` once, before executing ALL tests (and obviously the same for `TearDown`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/README.html):

> TTestSetup
>
> TTestSetup can be used when you wish to set up state exactly once for
>   a test case class (the SetUp and TearDown methods are called once for
>   each test method). For example, if you were writing a suite of tests
>   to exercise some database code, you might subclass TTestSetup and use
>   it to open and close the database before executing the suite.

[An an example how to use TTestSetup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9848767/800214)